# get_option returning a different value from what's saved

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
function register_mysettings() {
//register our settings
register_setting( 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options_validate' );
add_settings_section('plugin_main', '', 'plugin_section_text', 'plugin');
add_settings_field('plugin_text_string', '', 'plugin_setting_string', 'plugin', 

'plugin_main');
}

function poly_admin_form() {
?>

<div class="wrap">
<h2>Change who the email and name is from</h2>
<?php if ($_REQUEST['settings-updated'] == 'true' ) : ?>
<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong><?php _e( 'Options saved' ); ?></strong></p></div>
<?php endif; // If the form has just been submitted, this shows the notification ?>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
<?php settings_fields('plugin_options'); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections('plugin'); ?>


<?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php } 

function plugin_section_text() {
echo '';
}

function plugin_setting_string() {
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
echo "
<tr valign='top'>
<th scope='row'>Admin Email</th>
<td><input type='text' id='plugin_text_string' name='plugin_options[text_string]' value='{$options['text_string']}' /></td>
</tr>

    <tr valign='top'>
    <th scope='row'>Website Name or Person Name</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='plugin_text_string' name='plugin_options[text_string_name]' value='{$options['text_string_name']}' /></td>
    </tr>
";
} 

        // validate our options
    function plugin_options_validate($input) {
    $options = get_option('plugin_options');
    $options['text_string'] = trim($input['text_string']);
    $options['text_string_name'] = trim($input['text_string_name']);
    if(empty($options)) {
    $options['text_string'] = 'nadogrand@gmail.com';
    $options['text_string_name'] = 'Polyindustry';
    }

return $options;
}


        //Sends bulk email
        function bulk_mail(){
    poly_subscription_activation();

    add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
    add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');

    function new_mail_from($old) {
     return $options['text_string'];
    }
    function new_mail_from_name($old) {
     return $options['text_string_name'];
    }
```

Comment: it returns some value i think from the database: dbe07810

Comment: Please *describe your problem*, rather than just dropping a big block of code and expecting others to dig through it to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `plugin_options_validate()` function the return value of `get_option( 'plugin_options' )` is never used.

Let's step through the function by adding some comments:

```
// Retrieve the options.
$options = get_option('plugin_options');

// Replace the options without checking if
// trim( $input['text_string'] ) and trim( $input['text_string_name'] )
// actually return strings and if $input['text_string'] and 
// $input['text_string_name'] have anything in them.
$options['text_string'] = trim($input['text_string']);
$options['text_string_name'] = trim($input['text_string_name']);

// This part never runs. `$options` will never be empty!
if ( empty( $options ) ) {
    $options['text_string'] = 'nadogrand@gmail.com';
    $options['text_string_name'] = 'Polyindustry';
}
```

Effectively, this function is the same thing you have written:

```
// Validate options.
function plugin_options_validate( $input ) {

    $options['text_string'] = trim( $input['text_string'] );
    $options['text_string_name'] = trim( $input['text_string_name'] );

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: No sure i get what you are saying i removed the if statement but i still get the same result
what i am trying to do is use the inputed values from the form in the functions below:
   
       add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
        add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');
    
        function new_mail_from($old) {
         return $options['text_string'];
        }
        function new_mail_from_name($old) {
         return $options['text_string_name'];
        }

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please use punctuation. Like periods and commas. so I can tell where your sentences begin and end. Code in comments should go between back ticks. In code in your comment code, `$options['text_string']` and `$options['text_string_name']` have not been defined inside the functions, so they will always be empty. You are returning emptiness. And you should be seeing undefined index warnings in your PHP error logs.

Comment: ok i understand the it's empty in the `bulk_mail()` function but i use the same method in the  `plugin_setting_string()` function and i get the correct values. I just don't see why the values are returning empty in the `bulk_mail()` function

Comment: In the `plugin_setting_string()` function you set the value of `$options` with `$options = get_option('plugin_options');`. You have to do that again in each function you want to use the `$options` array in. PHP is a stupid list processor. It only does what you tell it to do in a list of PHP statements. In the `bulk_mail()` function, you are not are telling PHP to put any values in the  `$options` array, so it spits out a PHP Warning (which you are probably ignoring) and does the best that it can to guess what the heck you want.

Comment: Thanks man that worked, Could i have done it a better way?

Comment: Probably. You could follow [WordPress PHP Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/) and you might benefit from using a [PHP class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), but that can require a pretty steep learning curve.

Always remember that you are programming so that you will be able to understand it again in 6 to 12 months. In that time you will be a totally different person. Talk to yourself and tell yourself what you were trying to do when you wrote the code.